# Class styles are not applied in iOS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've encountered a rather strange issue with [our site's](http://rodengray.com) top navigation bar when viewed on an iPad. When a user taps on the "Brands" link, a drop-down menu should be shown, but it is not.

When a user taps on the "Departments" link the corresponding drop-down menu is shown properly and if the user subsequently taps on the "Brands" link the drop-down menu displays properly.

These drop-down menus are controlled via CSS class toggles triggered on hover by jQuery. When a user who hasn't previously tapped on the "Departments" link taps on the "Brands" link the class is applied correctly, however the styles aren't applied in a way that's visible to the user. I have verified this with the device emulator in Xcode as well as by debugging an iPad plugged in to my machine.

Additionally, [on certain pages of the site](http://rodengray.com/collections/new-arrivals/products/archivemadrasshirt), the drop-downs seem to work fine. I'm at a loss, I can't see what's going on here and I hope someone might point me in the right direction.

```
<style>

.tab {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 1px 0 0 0;
    background: #efefef;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.drop.active .tab {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 20;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

</style>

<nav id="nav" class="sixteen columns main-menu new">
    <ul id="tab-nav" class="new-nav">
    <li><a href="/collections/new-arrivals">New Arrivals</a></li>
    <li class="drop">
        <a href="/pages/designer-list">Brands</a>
        <div class="tab">
            <!-- SUBMENU CONTENT -->
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="drop">
        <a href="/collections/all">Departments</a>
        <div class="tab">
            <!-- SUBMENU CONTENT -->
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/blogs/the-look">The Look</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blogs/news">News</a></li>
    <li class="mobileonly"><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<script>
    // Tab Nav Toggle
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if ( viewWidth > 767 && is_touch_device() ) {
        $('.main-menu li.drop').hover(
          function() {
            $(this).find('a').first().click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
          }
        );
      } else if ( viewWidth > 767 &! is_touch_device() ) {
        $('.main-menu li.drop').hover(
          function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
          }
        );
      }
    });
</script>
```

I took another look and the issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with the javascript side of things. I tested again on my iPad with Javascript disabled (I have the effect applied with :hover as a no-js fallback) and the same weird behaviour persists. The "Brands" menu doesn't work until after you've tapped on the "Departments menu.

Comment: It isn't even on desktop. Using Safari right now.

Comment: If you could post the relevant markup (HTML/CSS/jQuery) for one of the problem areas, you might get a better answer. Just looking at the site though, it looks like your jQuery is toggling the list items and not the submenus.

Comment: @Shahar Could you tell me what version you're using? It's working with Safari 7, haven't tested it in older versions.

Comment: Please provide code examples

Comment: @MyCompassSpins I'll edit to add in some code. The class is applied to the list item, but child items are affected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's not precisely clear what you're trying to do, but I think I get the gist, and I'll edit my answer as we go.

First, `viewWidth` is not defined here, and so can't be used,  and `is_touch_device()` is not, to the best of my knowledge, a jQuery method.

Second, if you're targeting mobile devices, I'm guessing you want to fire these events when the window width is LESS THAN `767px`? If so, you've got the wrong operator. Take a look at this slightly modified and cleaned up version of your function, and take a look at the fiddle (linked below), and let me know if that's what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.drop').hover(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if ( width <= 596 ) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.tab').text("The parent list of the link whose text reads, '" + $(this).find('a').text() + "' now has the class, '" + $(this).attr('class') + "'.");
        }
    });

    $('li.drop').find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You have clicked the '" + $(this).text() + "' link.");
     });
});
```

A couple things to note:

I changed our target width to 596 because that's the default width of the JSFiddle window.
I used your `.tab` container as sort of a console to keep track of the class toggles.
I used alerts to let you know the click function is working properly.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T8LKu/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that out. I'll clean up what I have based on your recommendation. I'm targeting tablets here, so I'm actually trying to get devices with a width above 767px (also the viewWidth variable and is_touch_device function are defined elsewhere on the site). The issue seems like it's persisting anyways - I've added more info above...

Comment: I just looked at the site again, and I don't think any of these functions are a problem. It seems to work fine if the DOM loads at the target width, but goes haywire if you shrink the window after the DOM has loaded. Try shrinking the window and refreshing the page. That works for me (I'm on Chrome).